# Output from script - exec rm

Tags: linux, bash

I got a script which deletes files which are older than 2 days, usually it works properly, but for some reason it doesn't work fine today.

I want to find an option to get an output from script with error why the files are not deleted.

Could you tell me is there such option?

script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#script for cleaning logs from files older than two days

dir_name=/home/albert/scripts/files
file_log=/home/albert/scripts/info.log
{
find ${dir_name} -type f -name '*.log' -mtime +2 -exec rm -v {} \;
} >> ${file_log)
```

Comment: The command looks fine to me.  Can you elaborate on *"it doesn't work fine today"*?  How are you running the script, and what are the contents of the directory before and after running?

Comment: Possibly related: [Why does find -mtime +1 only return files older than 2 days?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92346/102168)

Comment: @joker20 : The command looks good. If there are errors, they should be displayed on the console, from which you invoke it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to add a redirection for standard error too, i.e. in the case you want to send it to the same file:

```
{
find ${dir_name} -type f -name '*.log' -mtime +2 -exec rm -v {} \;
} >> ${file_log) 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `find` option `-delete`:

- `-delete` - If the removal failed, an error message is issued.

```
find "${dir_name}" -type f -name '*.log' -mtime +2 -delete >> ${file_log} 2>&1
```

Example:

```
$ find /etc -name passwd -delete
find: cannot delete ‘/etc/pam.d/passwd’: Permission denied
find: cannot delete ‘/etc/passwd’: Permission denied
```